# Adding additional information as an afterthought

Tags: grammar

What is a natural way to add another object to a list as an afterthought? For example:

> 仕事で英語とピアノを教えています。フランス語____。
>
> For work I teach piano and English. Oh, and French too.

Comment: "Teach" as a habitual action should be 教えている instead of 教える, (which is " I will teach").

Answer (score 3):

The particle 「も」 will do the job.

> 仕事で英語とピアノを教えています。 フランス語**も**。

You can preface the afterthought with 「あと」or 「それと」 (or the like) to mark it explicitly as an addition to the previous statement.

> 仕事で英語とピアノを教えています。 **あと/それと**、フランス語も。

If you find it in your interest to be formal, it's best to complete your sentences.

> 仕事で英語とピアノを教えています。 **あと/それと/加えて**(this last one is more formal than the other two)、フランス語も教えています。

Answer (score 1):

Most naturally, we would say:

> 「（あっ、）それからフランス語も。」
>
> 「（あっ、）そしてフランス語も。」