# Explanation of でもあります？

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, particles, verbs

[image]

I saw this in my Genki I book and I don’t quite understand how to use でもあります. Also, how would I say this informally? パットはアメリカ人でもある？

Comment: @istrasci awesome! thanks. so real quick, if i wanted to say “she is american. she is also french,” would it be 彼女はアメリカ人です。フランス人でもある informally? and what about for いい adjectives?

Comment: See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6623/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36706/7810

Comment: @broccoliforest oh! thank you so much!